# One PNG image for all densities

Tags: android, png, screen-density

Can I use just one png image big enough for all densities? Or do I need to create one png image for every density?
I tries placing just one png image in drawable folder but it becomes blurry. So I placed that same image in the drawable-xxhdpi (my test device density) and it shows correctly (clear). I guess that the blurry effect is because it is multiplying for the scale factor of the screen density. The idea should be to say to Android to take the big image (xxxhdpi) and make it smaller (never bigger).

Comment: You are welcome to put an image in `res/drawable-anydpi/` (or `res/drawable-nodpi/` if you need to support really old devices). The downside of that (or using a single super-high-density image) is in performance and possible quality issues with the downsampled image. "I tries placing just one png image in drawable folder but it becomes blurry" -- for historical reasons, `res/drawable/` is the equivalent of `res/drawable-mdpi/`.

Comment: So It is more recommendable to use one for every density?

Comment: For icons and similar artwork, having a few densities is fairly typical. Usually, the graphic designer can supply those from whatever tools they are using.

Comment: Ok I'm gona make one for every density. But If I already have one for every density, it is necessary one for the anydpi or nodpi folder?

Comment: "But If I already have one for every density, it is necessary one for the anydpi or nodpi folder?" -- no.

Comment: I mean if I already have one for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi folders, do I still need one for anydpi or nodpi folder?

Comment: "do I still need one for anydpi or nodpi folder?" -- no. You probably do not need ones for all of those densities, either. Many times we choose some subset, trying to strike a balance between quality/performance and APK size/development headaches. Going back to your original plan, downsampling an `xxxhdpi` image all the way to `ldpi` is unlikely to turn out well. But downsampling an `mdpi` image to `ldpi` is likely to give you reasonable results. If you want to provide images for all those densities, that is fine, but if you wanted to only do 3-4 densities, that too is reasonable.

Comment: So If I have one png in `drawable-xxxhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, and `drawable` folders, then android gona take the one from `drawable` folder for the mdpi density, and gona take the same one from `drawable` folder multiplied by 0,75x for the ldpi density right?

Comment: Yes. Personally, I use `drawable-mdpi` instead of `drawable`, to maintain parallelism and to remind everyone what density that directory uses.

Comment: If I put the png only in `drawable` and no other folder, android gona take that png, multiply it by a scale factor depending on the screen density, and use it. But, if I put the png only in `drawable-mdpi` and no other folder, android gona take that png and use it as is, for all densities, without multiplying it, right?

Comment: "without multiplying it, right?" -- no. `drawable` and `drawable-mdpi` are equivalent. Both behave the same, and Android will resample the image based upon the actual screen density, treating the image as being `mdpi`.

Comment: Got it, thank you.